# Htaccess To Block wp-comments-post.php Spam

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, spam-prevention

I am trying to block spam bots from submitting comments to my customized Wordpress blog. I want to do this via .htaccess but something seems to be wrong with my code because many spam bots are still getting through. Here's my htaccess code. The trick is that my Wordpress installation is not located at the domain root but in /wordpress/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wordpress/wp-comments-post.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*mydomain.org.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your spam issue you have to identify where are the spam comments coming from and what to do with the requests

first option - if you want to redirect the malicious requests to your wp-comments.php somewhere
create a condition matching the suspicious ip address

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.89$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.90$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.100$
RewriteRule wp-comments-post\.php http://putyourredirecturlhere [R=301,L]
```

second option is deny suspicious ip addresses  to access any part of your site

```
order allow,deny
deny from 198.112.3.4 #Ip address you want to block
deny from 198.112.3.42 #Ip address you want to block
allow from all
```

Hope this helps
cheers

Comment: Is there any way to test it? Thanks

Comment: I have just realised that adding the rewrite code above will block all incoming comments to your site wether it's spam or not. You can test it by placing a comment in your site like what a normal visitor would do - comments won't work. 

I recommend you do the 2nd option. create a list of malicious ip address accessing your site then deny them in your .htaccess file. Please note that spammers/bots are sometimes disguising in other ip addresses that is not really malicious so you have to maintain your ip blacklist so you don't loose some real traffic.

Comment: If updating your .htaccess everytime you need to update your blacklist is not convenient for you then you may try using wordpress plugins:
see: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=block+ip

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I need to make my original code work. Block IP addresses is useless and time-consuming.

Comment: to resolve your spam issue you have to identify where are spam requests coming from and what to do with them. I have updated my answer
help that helps